# how can load image from this url

Tags: python, url, hash

i find a problem with this link, it gives me this error : "Bad URL hash"
[https://instagram.frba2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/291268648_561932488944102_7048684211968081492_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35\u0026_nc_ht=instagram.frba2-2.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=106\u0026_nc_ohc=ex7zqQH3HIAAX9pXd0A\u0026edm=AOQ1c0wBAAAA\u0026ccb=7-5\u0026oh=00_AT_S5DIzgMqfaIeSloZ758MbzRKKpHbkdP8AOwROkkpyBA\u0026oe=62DFBBCD\u0026_nc_sid=8fd12b](https://instagram.frba2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/291268648_561932488944102_7048684211968081492_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35%5Cu0026_nc_ht=instagram.frba2-2.fna.fbcdn.net%5Cu0026_nc_cat=106%5Cu0026_nc_ohc=ex7zqQH3HIAAX9pXd0A%5Cu0026edm=AOQ1c0wBAAAA%5Cu0026ccb=7-5%5Cu0026oh=00_AT_S5DIzgMqfaIeSloZ758MbzRKKpHbkdP8AOwROkkpyBA%5Cu0026oe=62DFBBCD%5Cu0026_nc_sid=8fd12b)

Comment: You get the same Error if you click on it. Are you sure you have the right url to the right picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace all instances of "\u0026" with "&" and it will work.